# How to make the window full screen with Javascript (stretching all over the screen)

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

How can I make a visitor's browser go fullscreen using JavaScript, in a way that works with IE, Firefox and Opera?

Comment: link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030928/browser-fullscreen-window-fullscreentrue-not-working

Comment: its inner application , not for the public . im not going to abuse any one

Comment: You could, pragmatically, ask the user: `sprintf('Dear user, the best experience with this site is in fullscreen mode. To view this site full screen, press %s.', _get_browsers_full_Screen_key())`

Comment: I am curious how the youtube fullscreen works. Anyone knows the answer?

Comment: this is done by the flash player not the browser

Comment: For a state of the art overview look here: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/

Comment: He is asking a question. That's is his ( her ) problem to use or not use fullscreen. Comercial sites don't like that because nobody can see the adds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set window to fullscreen (REAL fullscreen; F11 functionality) by javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179535/set-window-to-fullscreen-real-fullscreen-f11-functionality-by-javascript)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10082234/3656152 has the best solution for me. I have this working in a Blazor application on Chrome 

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is as close as you can get to full screen in JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = maxWindow;

    function maxWindow() {
        window.moveTo(0, 0);

        if (document.all) {
            top.window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
        }

        else if (document.layers || document.getElementById) {
            if (top.window.outerHeight < screen.availHeight || top.window.outerWidth < screen.availWidth) {
                top.window.outerHeight = screen.availHeight;
                top.window.outerWidth = screen.availWidth;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: look at the link/accepted answer in the link  haim evgi posted ... you're not supposed to be able to resize the browser. You can however maximize within the browsers window (that how I read it)

Comment: Strange, I just re-tested this script in FF 3.5 and it seemed to work fine... what are we missing?

Comment: Depends on your javascript permission settings in Options. You can toggle js control over window features.

Comment: This happened last time a site used code like that and I didn't block it: http://dorward.me.uk/tmp/fullscreen.jpeg

Comment: Take a look at the webkit-fullscreen API: http://bleeding-edge-tlv.appspot.com/#28 (from #gdd2011)

Comment: THIS IS OLD. LOOK BELOW FOR THE SOLUTION!

Comment: `moveTo` and `resizeTo` are DOM0: not in any standard.

Comment: Might help anyone, Works in **all Browsers** tested for me its working. `<script> 
 var popupScreenParameters = [
 'height='+screen.height,
 'width='+screen.width,
      'fullscreen=yes'
     ].join(',');
     
      var windowVariable = window.open('popupUrl',"popupName",popupScreenParameters);
      windowVariable .moveTo(0,0); </script>`

Comment: The answer by @Tower should be accepted, This is old & not working.

Comment: @user63898 Could you please "unaccept" this answer so that we can get it off the top of the list? You even said yourself that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 318):

In newer browsers such as Chrome 15, Firefox 10, Safari 5.1, IE 10 this is possible. It's also possible for older IE's via ActiveX depending on their browser settings.

Here's how to do it:

```
function requestFullScreen(element) {
    // Supports most browsers and their versions.
    var requestMethod = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.msRequestFullScreen;

    if (requestMethod) { // Native full screen.
        requestMethod.call(element);
    } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { // Older IE.
        var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        if (wscript !== null) {
            wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
        }
    }
}

var elem = document.body; // Make the body go full screen.
requestFullScreen(elem);
```

The user obviously needs to accept the fullscreen request first, and there is not possible to trigger this automatically on pageload, it needs to be triggered by a user (eg. a button)

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode

Comment: Currently available in Chrome 15, Firefox 10, and Safari 5.1. See this [hacks.mozilla.org blog post](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/) for details on the current state of play.

Comment: Fantastic, any way to exit full screen?

Comment: A few things. In IE this will obviously ignore the element and full screen everything. If you do want to full screen everything pass in `document.documentElement` that will ensure you'll get the correct root element('html' or 'body'). And use can use `cancelFullscreen()` to close it (or send 'F11' again for IE).

Comment: It can only be triggered by the user (for example via a fullscreen button). Automatic fullscreen during onload is not possible.

Comment: spelling error for IE, should be msRequestFullScreen, as in the docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265028(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: My JSLint said warned "ActiveXObject undefined" on  ````var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");```` --- i can write window.ActiveXObject instead of just ActiveXObject here and make JSLint happy without crashing the code for IE right?

Comment: Would be awesome to have a cancel function included in this answer, as well as warning that you cant let the user enter stuff using the keyboard when in fullscreen (unless requested in chrome...) for security reasons

Comment: The only problem is when I click on a link in the same domain.

Comment: What have you thought of my god old friend opera browser?

Comment: @DanielB - `element.msRequestFullScreen` is incorrect. It should be `element.msRequestFullscreen` with a lowercase s for Fullscreen. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn254939(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: @thecoolmacdude today you are right, but I'm not sure, if it you were in 2014.

Comment: A nice high-level abstract API you can use is Sindre Sorhus' Screenfull.js module (https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js) which should support the Opera browser as well. It takes care of the vendor prefixes.

Comment: Better to use `var elem = document.documentElement` instead of `document.body` as it uses the correct background-color.

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Fullscreen request denied` error... dont works

Comment: This seems to remove any styling on html or body in Edge

Answer (score 69):

The following code requests the Web page to go full screen in modern Web browsers. See this answer's edit history for code to enable full screen for older Web browsers, including Internet Explorer.

```
var el = document.documentElement,
    rfs = el.requestFullscreen;
if(typeof rfs!="undefined" && rfs){
  rfs.call(el);
}
```

See also:

- [Chrome Fullscreen API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836204/chrome-fullscreen-api) (note, however, that
  `requestFullscreen` "only works during" "[m]ost UIEvents and MouseEvents, such as click and keydown, etc.", "so it cannot be used maliciously".)

Comment: Works on IE 8 above, FF10 above (tried in FF 9, it doesn't work), tested on Chrome 18

Comment: @Peter O.  "should be placed in an event handler", any way to trigger it onload?

Comment: @FrancisP: No; neither "load" nor "DOMContentLoaded" is an applicable UIEvent or MouseEvent for the Fullscreen API.

Comment: Thanks for "(note, however, that requestFullScreen "only works during" "[m]ost UIEvents and MouseEvents, such as click and keydown, etc.", "so it cannot be used maliciously".)"

Comment: Yes `documentElement` is better than `body` for me.

Answer (score 31):

Here is a complete solution to get in and out of full screen mode (aka cancel, exit, escape)

```
        function cancelFullScreen() {
            var el = document;
            var requestMethod = el.cancelFullScreen||el.webkitCancelFullScreen||el.mozCancelFullScreen||el.exitFullscreen||el.webkitExitFullscreen;
            if (requestMethod) { // cancel full screen.
                requestMethod.call(el);
            } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { // Older IE.
                var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                if (wscript !== null) {
                    wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
                }
            }
        }

        function requestFullScreen(el) {
            // Supports most browsers and their versions.
            var requestMethod = el.requestFullScreen || el.webkitRequestFullScreen || el.mozRequestFullScreen || el.msRequestFullscreen;

            if (requestMethod) { // Native full screen.
                requestMethod.call(el);
            } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { // Older IE.
                var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                if (wscript !== null) {
                    wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
                }
            }
            return false
        }

        function toggleFullScreen(el) {
            if (!el) {
                el = document.body; // Make the body go full screen.
            }
            var isInFullScreen = (document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||  (document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen);

            if (isInFullScreen) {
                cancelFullScreen();
            } else {
                requestFullScreen(el);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: What about `msIsFullScreen`?

Comment: The spec has changed. `webkitCancelFullScreen` is now `webkitExitFullscreen`.
http://generatedcontent.org/post/70347573294/is-your-fullscreen-api-code-up-to-date-find-out-how-to

Comment: the first part of this logical and operation is redundant and should be removed ````document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null````

Comment: change the `elem` in `toggleFull()` from `document.body` to `document.documentElement` to fix left and right margin issue

Answer (score 16):

You can use [The fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode)
You can see [an example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/fullscreen.html)

> The fullscreen API provides an easy way for web content to be
>   presented using the user's entire screen. This article provides
>   information about using this API.

Answer (score 12):

This function work like a charm

```
function toggle_full_screen()
{
    if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) || (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen))
    {
        if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen){
            document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();
        }
        else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen){ /* Firefox */
            document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
        }
        else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen){   /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
            document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
        else if (document.msRequestFullscreen){ /* IE/Edge */
            document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (document.cancelFullScreen){
            document.cancelFullScreen();
        }
        else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen){ /* Firefox */
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        }
        else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen){   /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        }
        else if (document.msExitFullscreen){ /* IE/Edge */
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        }
    }
}
```

To use it just call:

```
toggle_full_screen();
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me, except it exits when you navigate :(

Answer (score 11):

> **The new html5 technology –** fullscreen API gives us an easy way to
>   present a web page content in full-screen mode. We are about to give
>   you detailed information about the fullscreen mode. Just try to
>   imagine about all possible advantages which you can get using this
>   technology – full-screen photo albums, videos, and even games.

But before we describe this new technology, I have to note that this technology is experimental, and ***supported by all major Browsers***.

**You can find the full tutorial here :** http://www.css-jquery-design.com/2013/11/javascript-jquery-fullscreen-browser-window-html5-technology/

**Here is working Demo :** http://demo.web3designs.com/javascript-jquery-fullscreen-browser-window-html5-technology.htm

Comment: @Ian It is working in IE edge. Older version of IE is not supporting this.

Answer (score 9):

I've used this...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>

<head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function fullScreen(theURL) {
            window.open(theURL, '', 'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=auto');
        }
        // End -->
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">
        Open In Full Screen
    </h1>
    <div style="text-align: center;"><br>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fullScreen('http://google.com');">
            Open Full Screen Window
        </a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: window.open(theURL, '', 'fullscreen=yes', 'scrollbars=auto');  There is a parens problem on this line

Comment: That is from the parent though. Not helpful when the window has already been opened.

Answer (score 9):

Simple example from: http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/26517/using-the-browsers-new-html5-fullscreen-capabilities/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function goFullscreen(id) {
    // Get the element that we want to take into fullscreen mode
    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    // These function will not exist in the browsers that don't support fullscreen mode yet, 
    // so we'll have to check to see if they're available before calling them.

    if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      // This is how to go into fullscren mode in Firefox
      // Note the "moz" prefix, which is short for Mozilla.
      element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
      // This is how to go into fullscreen mode in Chrome and Safari
      // Both of those browsers are based on the Webkit project, hence the same prefix.
      element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
   }
   // Hooray, now we're in fullscreen mode!
  }
</script>

<img class="video_player" src="image.jpg" id="player"></img>
<button onclick="goFullscreen('player'); return false">Click Me To Go Fullscreen! (For real)</button>
```

Answer (score 7):

**Create Function**

```
function toggleFullScreen() {

            if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||
                    (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
             $scope.topMenuData.showSmall = true;
                if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {
                    document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();
                } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                    document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
                } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                    document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
                }
            } else {

                  $scope.topMenuData.showSmall = false;
                if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
                    document.cancelFullScreen();
                } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
                } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                    document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
                }
            }
        }
```

**In Html Put Code like**

```
<ul class="unstyled-list fg-white">

            <li class="place-right" data-ng-if="!topMenuData.showSmall" data-ng-click="toggleFullScreen()">Full Screen</li>
            <li class="place-right" data-ng-if="topMenuData.showSmall" data-ng-click="toggleFullScreen()">Back</li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: if statement doesn't seem to detect that in full screen mode in IE 11 (so doesn't close).

Answer (score 6):

Try [screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js). It's a nice cross-browser solution that should work for Opera browser as well.

> Simple wrapper for cross-browser usage of the JavaScript Fullscreen API, which lets you bring the page or any element into fullscreen. Smoothens out the browser implementation differences, so you don't have to.

[Demo](https://sindresorhus.com/screenfull.js/).

Answer (score 4):

Luckily for unsuspecting web users this cannot be done with just javascript. You would need to write browser specific plugins, if they didn't already exist, and then somehow get people to download them. The closest you can get is a maximized window with no tool or navigation bars but users will still be able to see the url.

`window.open('http://www.web-page.com', 'title' , 'type=fullWindow, fullscreen, scrollbars=yes');">`

This is generally considered bad practice though as it removes a lot of browser functionality from the user.

Answer (score 4):

Now that the full screen APIs are more widespread and appear to be maturing, why not try [Screenfull.js](https://sindresorhus.com/screenfull.js/)? I used it for the first time yesterday and today our app goes truly full screen in (almost) all browsers!

Be sure to couple it with the `:fullscreen` pseudo-class in CSS. See https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-full-screen-api/ for more.

Comment: Amazing little script. Using it on my website now at www.StarCommanderOnline.com. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

This may support

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default5.aspx.cs" Inherits="PRODUCTION_Default5" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function max()
            {
               window.open("", "_self", "fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=auto"); 
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="max()">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        This is Test Page
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you Try:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function go_full_screen(){
      var elem = document.documentElement;
      if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
        elem.requestFullscreen();
      } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
        elem.msRequestFullscreen();
      } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      }
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="go_full_screen();">Full Screen / Compress Screen</a>
```

Comment: Seems to fail for me in Chrome 76 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

**This will works to show your window in full screen**

***Note:*** *For this to work, you need Query from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js*

Or make have  javascript link like this.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

   <div id="demo-element">
        <span>Full Screen Mode Disabled</span>
        <button id="go-button">Enable Full Screen</button>
    </div>
    <script>
    function GoInFullscreen(element) {
        if(element.requestFullscreen)
            element.requestFullscreen();
        else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen)
            element.mozRequestFullScreen();
        else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen)
            element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        else if(element.msRequestFullscreen)
            element.msRequestFullscreen();
    }

    function GoOutFullscreen() {
        if(document.exitFullscreen)
            document.exitFullscreen();
        else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen)
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        else if(document.webkitExitFullscreen)
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        else if(document.msExitFullscreen)
            document.msExitFullscreen();
    }

    function IsFullScreenCurrently() {
        var full_screen_element = document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement || null;

        if(full_screen_element === null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    $("#go-button").on('click', function() {
        if(IsFullScreenCurrently())
            GoOutFullscreen();
        else
            GoInFullscreen($("#demo-element").get(0));
    });

    $(document).on('fullscreenchange webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange MSFullscreenChange', function() {
        if(IsFullScreenCurrently()) {
            $("#demo-element span").text('Full Screen Mode Enabled');
            $("#go-button").text('Disable Full Screen');
        }
        else {
            $("#demo-element span").text('Full Screen Mode Disabled');
            $("#go-button").text('Enable Full Screen');
        }
    });</script>
```

Comment: this seems to be working for most browsers, Does not seems to work on Safari on iOS. Did you find any workaround for that?

Answer (score 2):

Those days, one line is enough:

```
document.documentElement.requestFullscreen()
```

Supported by all major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function fullScreen(theURL) {
window.open(theURL, '', 'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=auto' );
}
</script>
```

For calling from script use this code,

```
window.fullScreen('fullscreen.jsp');
```

or with hyperlink use this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fullScreen('fullscreen.jsp');"> 
Open in Full Screen Window</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox 10, you can make the current page go fullscreen (real fullscreen with no window chrome) using this javascript:

```
window.fullScreen = true;
```

Comment: The term "supposed to" is so overloaded in software.  In some browsers it is read-only.  Firefox 10 lets you set it.

Answer (score 0):

A Q&D way to go full screen, if you are in a "kiosk" situation, is to feed an F11 to the browser window after it's up and running. This is not pretty starting up and the user might be able to poke a touch screen at the top and get a semi-full-screen view, but feeding the F11 might do in a pinch or just to get started on a project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my full solution for `Full Screen` and `Exit Full Screen` both (many thanks to help from tower's answer above):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.is_fs = false;
$.requestFullScreen = function(calr)
{
    var element = document.body;

    // Supports most browsers and their versions.
    var requestMethod = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.msRequestFullScreen;

    if (requestMethod) { // Native full screen.
        requestMethod.call(element);
    } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { // Older IE.
        var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        if (wscript !== null) {
            wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
        }
    }

    $.is_fs = true;    
    $(calr).val('Exit Full Screen');
}

$.cancel_fs = function(calr)
{
    var element = document; //and NOT document.body!!
    var requestMethod = element.exitFullScreen || element.mozCancelFullScreen || element.webkitExitFullScreen || element.mozExitFullScreen || element.msExitFullScreen || element.webkitCancelFullScreen;

    if (requestMethod) { // Native full screen.
    requestMethod.call(element);
    } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { // Older IE.
        var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        if (wscript !== null) {
            wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
        }
    }    

    $(calr).val('Full Screen');    
    $.is_fs = false;
}

$.toggleFS = function(calr)
{    
    $.is_fs == true? $.cancel_fs(calr):$.requestFullScreen(calr);
}

});
```

//
CALLING:

```
<input type="button" value="Full Screen" onclick="$.toggleFS(this);" />
```

Answer (score -1):

`function fs(){plr.requestFullscreen();document.exitFullscreen()};` or `function fs(){(plr.offsetWidth==360)?plr.requestFullscreen():document.exitFullscreen()}`

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>

<style>
body{background:#000}
#plr{position:relative;background:#fff;width:360px}
#vd{width:100%;background:grey}
button{width:48px;height:48px;border:0;background:grey}
</style>

</head><body>

<div id="plr">
<video id="vd" src="video.mp4"></video>
<button onclick="(plr.offsetWidth==360)?plr.requestFullscreen():document.exitFullscreen()">fs</button>
<button onclick="plr.requestFullscreen();document.exitFullscreen()">fs2</button>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Fullscreen with JavaScript</h2>
    <p>Click on the button to open the video in fullscreen mode.</p>
    <button onclick="openFullscreen();">Open Video in Fullscreen Mode</button>
    <p><strong>Tip:</strong> Press the "Esc" key to exit full screen.</p>
    
    <video width="100%" controls id="myvideo">
      <source src="rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="rain.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    
    
    <script>
    var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");
    function openFullscreen() {
      if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
        elem.requestFullscreen();
      } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
        elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
        elem.msRequestFullscreen();
      }
    }
    </script>
    
    <p>Note: Internet Explorer 10 and earlier versions do not support the msRequestFullscreen() method.</p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Source:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen.asp