# How to implement exact full-screen in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I tried [How to make the window full screen with Javascript (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen/1125113#1125113),

but it's not working.

**EDIT**

I mean it should fill all of my computer by full-screen.

Comment: in what way is it not working? on what browser(s) have you tried? Did you get any error messages?

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
alert("Please press F11");
```

There's no way to make an existing window completely fullscreen in Javascript.

The closest you can get is to open a popup window and pray that it doesn't get blocked by popup blockers, like this:

```
open("http://google.com", null, 
  "height=" + screen.availHeight + ",width=" + screen.availWidth + ",status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no")
```

Comment: Are you so sure that it's impossible to implement F11 effect?