# How do I emulate pressing F-11 in a browser using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make in Javascript full screen windows (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)

How do I emulate pressing F-11 in a browser using Javascript?
(I assume it will be different in Chrome,IE and FF?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Browsers do not expose an API that makes this possible.

Answer (score 4):

This used to be possible (anybody remember "chromeless windows" in IE4 or 5? Those were *brilliant*!) but isn't any more for security reasons.

Almost all browsers come with a "Kiosk mode" (Internet Explorer e.g. using `iexplore -k` on the command line) that enables full-screen browsing but obviously, this has to be initiated on the client's end.

Answer (score 0):

Using JS, - move the window to 0,0 make the width the same as the screen width, make the height same height as the page.