# How to make browser full screen on page load using javascript with timer control

Tags: .net, javascript, asp.net

I want a browser to go full screen as soon as my page loads. Is it possible in javascript.
I know the shortcut key for this F11 but requirement is on page load only.

After reading the solution provided below. I achieved full screen but here i got a trap. I was using timer to make my page postback to get fresh data after every 5 second. And here I found after every 5 sec new window opens up but I want full screen to go only once and next time content gets refreshed there itself.

Comment: Kiosk mode (full screen with hidden menu, which F11 does) can't be done through Javascript for security reasons.  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function OpenfullScreen(URL) {
    window.open(URL, '', 'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=auto');
}
```

call this function from where you are opening the page

Comment: Is this even allowed and not blocked by the browser? Be cause I would harm anyone who whould do this without warning.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the 
window.open('yourlocation.htm', 'New window name', 'fullscreen=1');

**NOTE** THAT fullscreen is ONLY supported in I.E. browser. Not recommended to use since it is browser dependent.

### Function Specification

the format of window.open() is 
window.open (URL, windowName[, windowFeatures])

URL is the URL page you trying to open
windowName is the name given to this window

Windowfeatures is the additional parameter you would like this window to have

- status    -status bar at the bottom of
  the window. e.g. "status=1"
- toolbar   -standard browser toolbar,
  with Back and Forward button etc.
  e.g. "toolbar=0" mean no toolbar
  location
- Location entry field where
  you enter the URL. e.g. "location=0"
- menubar   -menu bar of the window e.g.
  "menubar=1"
- directories -The standard
  browser directory buttons e.g.
  "directories=1"
- resizable
  -Allow/Disallow the user to resize the window. e.g. "resizble=0"
- scrollbars -Enable the scrollbars if
  the document is bigger than the
  window e.g. "scrollbars=1"
- height    -Specifies the height of the
  window in pixels
- width -Specifies the
  width of the window in pixels.

Answer (score 1):

```
function OpenfullScreen(URL) {
    window.open(URL, '', 'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=auto, resizble=yes, status=yes, toolbar=yes,menubar=yes, scrollbars=no');
}
```

You can specify the width and height of the page too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" /> to refresh the browser in every 5 seconds.

place this code in the new window instead of the one that call it