# onclick go full screen

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a web-app for the upcoming Chrome Web-store. Is there a way to simulate F11 being pressed? Or simply a command that will make the current window go full screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set window to fullscreen (REAL fullscreen; F11 functionality) by javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179535/set-window-to-fullscreen-real-fullscreen-f11-functionality-by-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the window full screen with Javascript (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-the-window-full-screen-with-javascript-stretching-all-over-the-scre)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[It's possible with JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode).

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.msRequestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
```

Comment: +1. I hate websites/apps resizing my browser. If I need to resize it or fullscreen it I'll do it myself!

Comment: If you prefer to smoothe over the various browser implementations, try Screenfull.js (https://sindresorhus.com/screenfull.js/) - it works a treat!

Comment: It exists full screen on page load. what can I do to prevent that?

Comment: I tried it for videos and it works, but I can't seem to make it work for other files, such as gltf. Have any ideas as to why that's happening?

Answer (score 145):

I realize this is a very old question, and that the answers provided were adequate, since is active and I came across this by doing some research on fullscreen, I leave here one update to this topic:

There is a way to ***"simulate"*** the **F11 key**, but cannot be automated, the user actually needs to click a button for example, in order to trigger the full screen mode.

- #### Toggle Fullscreen status on button click

  **[With this example](https://db.tt/e6jqjQU0)**, the user can switch to and from fullscreen mode by clicking a button:

  HTML element to act as trigger:

  ```
  <input type="button" value="click to toggle fullscreen" onclick="toggleFullScreen()">
  ```

  JavaScript:

  ```
  function toggleFullScreen() {
    if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||    
     (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
      if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {  
        document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();  
      } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {  
        document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();  
      } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {  
        document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);  
      }  
    } else {  
      if (document.cancelFullScreen) {  
        document.cancelFullScreen();  
      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {  
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();  
      } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {  
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();  
      }  
    }  
  }
  ```
- #### Go to Fullscreen on button click

  **[This example](https://db.tt/cNSKGt6A)** allows you to enable full screen mode without making alternation, ie you switch to full screen but to return to the normal screen will have to use the F11 key:

  HTML element to act as trigger:

  ```
  <input type="button" value="click to go fullscreen" onclick="requestFullScreen()">
  ```

  JavaScript:

  ```
  function requestFullScreen() {

    var el = document.body;

    // Supports most browsers and their versions.
    var requestMethod = el.requestFullScreen || el.webkitRequestFullScreen 
    || el.mozRequestFullScreen || el.msRequestFullScreen;

    if (requestMethod) {

      // Native full screen.
      requestMethod.call(el);

    } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") {

      // Older IE.
      var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

      if (wscript !== null) {
        wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
      }
    }
  }
  ```

---

### Sources found along with useful information on this subject:

[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode)

[How to make in Javascript full screen windows (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1125084/352449)

[How to make browser full screen using F11 key event through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495373/how-to-make-browser-full-screen-using-f11-key-event-through-javascript)

[Chrome Fullscreen API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836204/chrome-fullscreen-api)

[jQuery fullscreen event plugin, version 0.2.0](https://github.com/ruidlopes/jquery-fullscreen)

[jquery-fullscreen-plugin](https://github.com/kayahr/jquery-fullscreen-plugin/)

Comment: @Zuul - I referenced your answer to answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495373/how-to-make-browser-full-screen-using-f11-key-event-through-javascript/25245972#25245972), however I updated the JS code to add IE compatibility.

Comment: @Zuul Your two examples now link to dropbox hosted 404's

Comment: The IE-specific fullscreen methods are `msRequestFullscreen` and `msExitFullscreen` (note the lower-case `s`)

Comment: How would this code be modified for Chrome-only (not cross-browser)?

Comment: Links broken :(

Comment: Pretty sure the first test should be `if (!document.fullScreenElement && !document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen) {`

Comment: This has a bunch of typos; fullScreen vs fullscreen.

Comment: @LawrenceDol Can you be more specific and let us know what browser complained of what and where?

Comment: Works like magic, love it

Answer (score 7):

## Short personal bookmarklet version

```
javascript: document.body.webkitRequestFullScreen();
```

[go fullscreen](http://delete_me/javascript:document.body.webkitRequestFullScreen();) ← You can drag this link to your bookmark bar to create the bookmarklet, but you have to edit its URL afterwards: Delete everything before `javascript`, including the single slash: <s>`http://delete_me/`</s>`javascript:`[…]

This works for me in Google Chrome.  You have to test whether it works in your environment and otherwise use a different wording of the function call, e.g. [`javascript:document.body.requestFullScreen();`](http://delete_me/javascript:document.body.requestFullScreen();) – see the other answers for the possible variants.

<sub>Based on the answers by @Zuul and @default – thanks!</sub>

Comment: I found I had to add a trigger to the page in Firefox (mobile and desktop) to stay within the security restrictions. I made the button click both enter fullscreen and delete itself.
`javascript:void%20document.body.appendChild((e=%3E%7Be.onclick=()=%3E%7Bdocument.documentElement.requestFullscreen();e.parentNode.removeChild(e)%7D;e.innerHTML='FULLSCREEN';e.style='position:fixed;left:0;top:0;z-index:999999999999';return%20e%7D)(document.createElement('BUTTON')))`
and use `void` to avoid replacing the current doc with the function's return value.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to switch the whole tab to fullscreen (just like F11 keypress) `document.documentElement` is the element you are looking for:

```
function go_full_screen(){
    var elem = document.documentElement;
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a difference between using `document.documentElement` and `document.body` (like @Zuul does in his older answer above)?

Answer (score 2):

I tried other answers on this question, and there are mistakes with the different browser APIs, particularly `Fullscreen` vs `FullScreen`. Here is my code that works with the major browsers (as of Q1 2019) and should continue to work as they standardize.

```
function fullScreenTgl() {
    let doc=document,elm=doc.documentElement;
    if      (elm.requestFullscreen      ) { (!doc.fullscreenElement   ? elm.requestFullscreen()       : doc.exitFullscreen()        ) }
    else if (elm.mozRequestFullScreen   ) { (!doc.mozFullScreen       ? elm.mozRequestFullScreen()    : doc.mozCancelFullScreen()   ) }
    else if (elm.msRequestFullscreen    ) { (!doc.msFullscreenElement ? elm.msRequestFullscreen()     : doc.msExitFullscreen()      ) }
    else if (elm.webkitRequestFullscreen) { (!doc.webkitIsFullscreen  ? elm.webkitRequestFullscreen() : doc.webkitCancelFullscreen()) }
    else                                  { console.log("Fullscreen support not detected.");                                          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways to do that:

- [The JavaScript Source: Navigation: Full Screen Window](http://javascript.internet.com/navigation/full-screen.html)
- [Javascript to open a full screen window](http://www.pptools.com/ppt2html/FAQ00140.htm)

I'd suggest, provide a popup asking the user if s/he wants to go full screen and then call this javascript accordingly.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: The first link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

```
//set height of html
$("html").css("height", screen.height);
//set width of html
$("html").css("width", screen.width);
//go to full screen mode
document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");
function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
      elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
      elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
//Internet Explorer 10 and earlier does not support the msRequestFullscreen() method.
```

Answer (score -1):

so simple 
try this

```html
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: null -->
```