# How to make browser full screen using F11 key event through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, screen, fullscreen, keyevent

I want to make my browser full screen. Same as when we do F11 key event. I found some examples such as

```
function maxwin() {
    var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    if (wscript!=null) {
         wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
    }
}
```

Which does not work on mozilla or any other latest browsers. Please let me know if there is any way to sort out this problem.

Thanks. (In advance.)

Answer (score 13):

This is now possible in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE(11).

Following the pointers by Zuul on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900701/onclick-go-full-screen), I edited his code to include IE11 and the option to full screen any element of choice on your page.

JS:

```
function toggleFullScreen(elem) {
    // ## The below if statement seems to work better ## if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) || (document.msfullscreenElement && document.msfullscreenElement !== null) || (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
    if ((document.fullScreenElement !== undefined && document.fullScreenElement === null) || (document.msFullscreenElement !== undefined && document.msFullscreenElement === null) || (document.mozFullScreen !== undefined && !document.mozFullScreen) || (document.webkitIsFullScreen !== undefined && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
        if (elem.requestFullScreen) {
            elem.requestFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            elem.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
            elem.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
    } else {
        if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
            document.cancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="click to toggle fullscreen" onclick="toggleFullScreen(document.body)">
```

Where "document.body" is any element you so wish.

Also note that trying to run these full screen commands from the console do not appear to work on Chrome or IE. I did have success with Firebug in Firefox though.

One other thing to note is that these "full screen" commands don't have a vertical scrollbar, you need to specify this within the CSS:

```
*:fullscreen
*:-ms-fullscreen,
*:-webkit-full-screen,
*:-moz-full-screen {
   overflow: auto !important;
}
```

The "!important" seems to be necessary for IE to render it

Comment: I've tried other solution. This best answer, 100% works.

Comment: Note the capital `S` in `requestFullScreen` afaik is deprecated (but possibly still in firefox) and should have a small `s`; `requestFullscreen`.

This took me a while to figure out

Answer (score 12):

use this code instead

```
var el = document.documentElement
, rfs = // for newer Webkit and Firefox
       el.requestFullScreen
    || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
    || el.mozRequestFullScreen
    || el.msRequestFullScreen
;
if(typeof rfs!="undefined" && rfs){
  rfs.call(el);
} else if(typeof window.ActiveXObject!="undefined"){
  // for Internet Explorer
  var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  if (wscript!=null) {
     wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
  }
}
```

Source: [How to make in Javascript full screen windows (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)

Works and tested on Chrome, FF10 above, IE 8 above, Safari 5..

Comment: THANK YOU! I am running a blazor application, and this code snippet works out the box. Shot bru.

Comment: @Treby: And if we want to exit, then what will be the code??

Comment: Note the capital `S` in `requestFullScreen` afaik is deprecated (but possibly still in firefox) and should have a small `s`; `requestFullscreen`.

This took me a while to figure out

Answer (score 6):

Not possible without native code or a browser extension. The ActiveXObject only exists in the IE browser.

Comment: I wonder how much has changed since Sept. 21st, 2011?  Facebook now  (April 9, 2012) has a functionality to make its popovers fullscreen (at least certainly in Chrome), and I'm still certainly using the browser (and not flash) as I can "Inspect Element" and do other Chrome things..

Comment: Quite true: as @Treby points out there are full-screen APIs now emerging, so this may no longer be valid.

Comment: Note though that the Fullscreen API and F11 are [https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=794468](not the same thing).

Comment: This answer is now out of date - see the other answers in this thread for solutions that use the fullscreen API.

Answer (score -3):

now a days it is possible (at least webkit browsers at safari 5, chrome 16) with the

```
 webkitEnterFullscreen()
```

Firefox 10 also works. [check this link](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/)

no idea what i-e is doing in this topic