# How can Google Docs go fullscreen in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How can Google Docs go fullscreen in JavaScript?
In a **[Google Docs Presentation](https://docs.google.com/)**, when you press the `fullscreen` button at the lower left corner of the window, the window goes *fullscreen*.
It is not Flash so I am curious that how can Google do that?

### Added

Note that it is not creating a big window that fits the screen (that's fake fullscreen). It is actually in `fullscreen` mode, and Google Chrome asked for my permission.

Comment: where is the fullscreen button? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @tr4656, In a Webkit browser, open a Google Docs Presentation (new), and the button is at the lower left corner of the window.

Comment: OK, I myself did a little research on it and found out that a little trick would do it: `<button onclick="document.body.webkitRequestFullScreen()">Fullscreen</button>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems they are using the technique described in this article: http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/fullscreen

```
// Mozilla
element.mozRequestFullScreen();

// Webkit
element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
```

**Edit:** That article forgets to mention that if you want the whole page fullsreen you can do `document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen();`.

Answer (score 3):

I've tested the code given in this question on Internet Explorer 9:

[How to make browser full screen using F11 key event through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495373/how-to-make-browser-full-screen-using-f11-key-event-through-javascript)

At least for Internet Explorer 9, though, the permission dialog might be misleading.

Comment: Now we can make it goes fullscreen on the major browsers! Thanks.