# GWT: How to simulate F11 key press event?

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gwt-2.4, gwt-2.5

I was wondering, can we trigger any key press even in **GWT** without JSNI? For example, say I have a image or a button in the header of my application. On click of it I want to go **fullscreen** on browser which simulates **F11** key press. Again on click of the same image or button I want to exit from the full screen mode which simulates **ESC** key press.

I came to know through " [How to make browser full screen using F11 key event through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495373/how-to-make-browser-full-screen-using-f11-key-event-through-javascript) " that we can do via java script, so it must be possible to do that via JSNI code snippet. Is there any other solution possible which doesn't use JSNI code?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `Document.get().createKeyEvent` or similar [api](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Document.html).

```
NativeEvent event = Document.get().createKeyEvent(args.....);

DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(event, this);
```

Check which apis are deprecated before use.

Comment: DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(event, this) wont work for F11 and I dont know why

Comment: Check browser type and version . Reference https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/google-web-toolkit/0wd47vskJvE

Comment: I have tried the same approach around 3 months back using IE I believe and it dint work, I will try this first thing tomorrow

Comment: I tried this. This wont work in Firefox, Chrome as well as IE8