# Searching for a fullscreen image Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, fullscreen

I am searching for a free javascript image slider, which allows me to go fullscreen like on the youtube player or any other video player. Unfortunately I can just find sliders, which allow me to use the whole browser window, but they do not hide the windows explorer bar and the browsers bar.

I would be very pleasent for any advice.

With regards,

Andrej

Answer (score 0):

Actually you will not find a slider that does that automatically ... even if it has a full screen mood included ... still wouldn't hid the browser windows explorer.

If this feature is a must for you, you may search for a JavaScript/JQuery code that manipulates the window attributes (ex: width,height, ... etc).

There's a thread on Stackoverflow that discuss the same issue ... you may check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495373/how-to-make-browser-full-screen-using-f11-key-event-through-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Vide.js will be helpful for making full screen video player.
If you are making an image slider then go for any framework and choose sliders. In CSS make `width 100% height:100%` and `overflow: hidden` to prevent scrollbar.