# Chrome Fullscreen API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fullscreen

According to [this article](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/networking/google-chrome-web-browser-to-get-a-makeover/1499) Google Chrome 15 has a fullscreen JavaScript API.

I have tried to make it work but failed. I have also searched for official documentation in vain.

What does the fullscreen JavaScript API look like?

Comment: This is the proposed specification which is going to be implemented: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:FullScreenAPI#Proposed_Specification.

Comment: I've not been able to get it working either, though they did implement this in WebKit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43099. This is the Chromium bug which might be relevant: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73923.

Comment: You can launch it in "kiosk mode" (full screen, no controls) like this: chrome.exe –kiosk http://...

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The API only works during user interaction, so it cannot be used maliciously. Try the following code:

```
addEventListener("click", function() {
    var el = document.documentElement,
      rfs = el.requestFullscreen
        || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
        || el.mozRequestFullScreen
        || el.msRequestFullscreen 
    ;

    rfs.call(el);
});
```

Comment: How is "user interaction" defined?

Comment: Most `UIEvent`s and `MouseEvent`s, such as `click` and `keydown`, etc.

Comment: This works to go into full screen for me but when the user navigates to the next page in my site, it exits full screen. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @alex9311 As far as I know, you need to use AJAX to update content. You can't leave the page.

Comment: this works with "click" but not "mouseenter". But mouseenter is ALSO a user-interaction.

Comment: @johny Fullscreen mode allows to fake any GUI (like VPN password entry window), and "user interaction" should make user suspect something. Also, it prevents webpages from covering the whole screen in uncontrollable way. Obviously, "mouseenter" and especially "mousemove" fail in both cases.

Answer (score 34):

I made a simple wrapper for the Fullscreen API, called [screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js), to smooth out the prefix mess and fix some inconsistencies in the different implementations. Check out the [demo](http://sindresorhus.com/screenfull.js/) to see how the Fullscreen API works.

Recommended reading:

- [Using the Fullscreen API in web browsers](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/)
- [MDN - Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode)

Comment: Wow - such a great plugin, thanks! Is there any way to open a link in fullscreen while the current tab remains non-fullscreen? didn't find anything like that in the demo.

Answer (score 18):

Here are some functions I created for working with fullscreen in the browser.

They provide both enter/exit fullscreen across most major browsers.

```
function isFullScreen()
{
    return (document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null)
         || document.mozFullScreen
         || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
}


function requestFullScreen(element)
{
    if (element.requestFullscreen)
        element.requestFullscreen();
    else if (element.msRequestFullscreen)
        element.msRequestFullscreen();
    else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen)
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen)
        element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}

function exitFullScreen()
{
    if (document.exitFullscreen)
        document.exitFullscreen();
    else if (document.msExitFullscreen)
        document.msExitFullscreen();
    else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen)
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen)
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
}

function toggleFullScreen(element)
{
    if (isFullScreen())
        exitFullScreen();
    else
        requestFullScreen(element || document.documentElement);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The following test works in Chrome 16 (dev branch) on X86 and Chrome 15 on Mac OSX Lion

http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/fullscreen.html

Comment: When I type "enterFullScreen()" from the console, it doesn't go fullscreen.

Comment: You must make the requestFullScreen() call on an element that you wish to display in fullscreen. There is no way to simply jump into the mode. Here is another excellent description of the FullScreen API by John Dyer with a full example http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Link 404s now .

Answer (score 0):

In Google's closure library project , there is a module which has do the job , below is the API and source code.

[Closure library fullscreen.js API](https://closure-library.googlecode.com/git-history/docs/local_closure_goog_dom_fullscreen.js.html)

[Closure libray fullscreen.js Code](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/dom/fullscreen.js)