# Full Screen mode not working while loading the web page in a new window

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse, scriptmanager

I used the following code segment to move from A.aspx web page to B.aspx web page and I need to load the B.aspx page in full screen mode in a separate window. I am able to load the content on a separate window but unable to make it to display in full screen. The window just appears to the half of the screen

```
Response.Redirect("B.aspx", "", "fullscreen=yes");
```

I have tried it with the ScriptManager as well but again I am facing the same problem. Following is the code segment.

```
string url = "B.aspx";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "window.open(' " + url + "', '', 'fullscreen=yes,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=yes' );", true);
```

I have also tried setting the width and height of the window and got the same output!

Note: The problem occurs on Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge browsers. When I run the program on Firefox, the page got loaded in full screen. Is this a browser problem or is there any way to achieve this where it is compatible with all the browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes and recommendations here:

1) [`Response.Redirect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirect?view=netframework-4.7.2) method only accept a maximum of 2 parameters, therefore you cannot use `fullscreen=yes` as third parameter.

2) `fullscreen=yes` as `window.open()` parameter only works for IE (and older Firefox), but not all versions supported ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)). You need to use browser specific APIs on the target page instead.

Hence, as mentioned before, you should add a function to call fullscreen API depending on the client browser:

```
function fullScreenMode(element) {
    if(element.requestFullscreen)
        element.requestFullscreen();
    else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen)
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen)
        element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    else if(element.msRequestFullscreen)
        element.msRequestFullscreen();
}
```

Then modify `RegisterStartupScript` like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", 
              "window.open('" + url + @"', '', 'resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=yes' );", true);
```

And call `fullScreenMode(document.documentElement)` function on the target page when user triggering certain DOM event, because some browsers put limitations to prevent pop-up window abuse in similar way to `window.open()` function.

Related issue:

[How to open a web page automatically in full screen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355370/how-to-open-a-web-page-automatically-in-full-screen-mode)

[Setting the whole window to be fullscreen in recent browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992328/setting-the-whole-window-to-be-fullscreen-in-recent-browsers)

Comment: Thankyou for your answer.  How and where can i call the fullScreenMode(document.documentElement) exactly? What did u mean by triggering certain DOM event?

Comment: You can call that function inside `B.aspx` page when a DOM event is triggered, e.g. by button click. Since recent browsers have limitation regarding `window.open()` parameters, you can't automatically set fullscreen mode with `fullscreen=yes` parameter.