# How to make chrome extension to be in full screen?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make chrome extension to be in full screen, but the max I can do is half width. More then that it just give me a scroll bar in the bottom..
How can I make it to be in full screen? meaning, the whole width of the chrome browser?
Thanks!

Comment: You're talking about a Browser Action popup window? I'm not sure those are able to be full-width windows. Try the Fullscreen API, but even that might not be possible. You may want to open a new tab with your extension's content instead.

Comment: You should accept Vincent Scheib's answer at the bottom. It is the correct, current, and "fully operational" answer.

Answer (score 13):

```
chrome.windows.update(windowId, { state: "fullscreen" })
```

See https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-update

Comment: But when you exit the full screen, your browser will not back to the state you entered before, how to solve that ??

Comment: What if I want it to be fullscreen on another display?

Answer (score 3):

In your extensions "background.js" script:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function (launchData) {
  chrome.app.window.create(
    // Url
    '/editor.html',
    // CreateWindowOptions
    {
            'width': 400,
            'height': 500
    },
    // Callback
    function(win) {
        win.contentWindow.launchData = launchData;
        win.maximize();
        win.show();
    });
});
```

Comment: It requires 'app.window' permission, but:
"'app.window' is only allowed for packaged apps, and this is a extension."

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the [fullScreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode) ?

Comment: Well, the answer with the link directly to the chrome API docs is still more applicable to a chrome-extension question.

Answer (score 1):

```
addEventListener("click", function() {
    var
          el = document.documentElement
        , rfs =
               el.requestFullScreen
            || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
            || el.mozRequestFullScreen
    ;
    rfs.call(el);
});
```

As seen in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7934009/525576)

Answer (score 0):

for general use on web pages in all browsers, include msRequestFullscreen

```
addEventListener("click", function () {
    var
          el = document.documentElement
        , rfs =
               el.requestFullScreen
            || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
            || el.mozRequestFullScreen
            || el.msRequestFullscreen
    ;
    if (rfs) { rfs.call(el); } else { console.log('fullscreen api not supported');}
});
```