# Open Chrome app within Chrome's main window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm fairly new to Chrome app development and was wondering if it's possible to run an app within Chrome's main window, like the TweetDeck app.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210116/how-to-make-chrome-extension-to-be-in-full-screen

Answer (score 0):

No. Chrome Apps' current goal is to provide a native-like app experience outside the Chrome browser. Today, with the exception of certain privileged APIs, putting an app in Chrome would be... well, it would be a website.

If you want an app in one of Chrome's tabs, why not just build a website? What does the open web lack for your project?

Note that we have been thinking about what it would mean for an app to be a component inside a webpage. You could imagine a Facebook Like button or a Google+ +1 button implemented as an app in a webpage in the same way that those buttons today are usually implemented as iframes. There are some interesting security properties that this approach would bring over iframes. But again, this doesn't seem to be what you had in mind. What you had in mind appears to be a regular website.