# How to make a full screen html popup in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Default popup.html of Chrome is of 600 * 800 size.

How can I produce a full screen popup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make chrome extension to be in full screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210116/how-to-make-chrome-extension-to-be-in-full-screen)

Answer (score 2):

Use screen.availWidth and screen.availHeight to calculate a suitable size for the height and width parameters in window.open()

Although this is likely to be close, it will not be maximised, nor accurate for everyone, especially if all the toolbars are shown.
visit [How to show fullscreen popup window in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172748/how-to-show-fullscreen-popup-window-in-javascript)