# How to adjust popup.html to full screen in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to chrome extension development. I have some questions:
 1. I tried my best to set the width of popup.html to full screen. But, couldn't. Is there any way.
2. When I switch tab in chrome, the extension is closing. Is there any way to remain even when the focus is switched from the extension.
3. popup.html looks like hanging from the extension icon in the tool bar. Is it possible to detach from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/41034446/1225070

Comment: No to all three questions. Open a separate window instead.

Comment: But I saw many extensions that did it.Example: Amazon scout.

Comment: You didn't. The extension wasn't showing the standard browserAction popup. It was either an in-page DOM element or a separate window.

Answer (score 2):

In popup code

```
chrome.windows.create({
    state: "fullscreen",
    url: location.url
})
```