# brackets-shell Enable Fullscreen

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded, brackets-shell

How do I enable fullscreen for brackets-shell (which implements CEF)?

I tried adding:

```
$('.somediv').get(0).webkitRequestFullScreen();
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything.

I just compile brackets-shell exactly as it comes. I can't tell definitively if brackets-shell comes with it available or not, and I can't tell where to check in the CEF code.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you need this workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836204/chrome-fullscreen-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I never could get the webkit version of full screen to work.

What I ended up doing was implementing my own full screen native function extension, and then calling that instead. Not as ideal, but it works.