# Popup Window That Covers Entire Screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, window

I have a very large interactive element and I would like it if I could make a certain popup cover the entire window of the browser including the search bar and the windows in addition to just the part of the browser that shows the webpage. Is that possible?

Comment: Fortunately this is not possible.

Comment: "Large" doesn't make too much sense nowadays: large for a 1366x?? laptop, for a 1920x1050 monitor, for a 320x480 smartphone, for a 1024 HiDPI/retina tablet?

Answer (score 3):

Look over here for full screen mode (also covers the statusbar of windows) (for Chrome and other modern browsers):

1. [Chrome Fullscreen API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836204/chrome-fullscreen-api)
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode

The user has to use a click event or another event, because there has to be an interaction.

Working example:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function() {

 var
          el = document.documentElement
        , rfs =
               el.requestFullScreen
            || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
            || el.mozRequestFullScreen
    ;
    rfs.call(el);
});
```

**Option 2**
If you want to make a shortcut to the current URL. Than you don't have a status bar or other tabs. For Chrome this works. You can do nav -> extra -> create shortcut. Save it to your desktop and open it. Now you only got your website in full screen. This can work if you want to use it like an application for customers. Give them a feeling of a stand alone application.

**Note:** There aren't much more options.