# Hide browser bar in mobile chrome app on a not scrollable page

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I have a HTML5 App, which is in a container with absolute position and 100% height of the body and therefore is not scrollable.

I want to hide the browser bar in Chrome browser on Android, to get more space on the screen. So, actually I am looking for an equivalent for the IOS meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" minimal-ui">
```

My idea was to add some pixels to the container's height

```
height: calc(100% + 50px);
```

and then use

```
window.scrollTo(0,50);
```

to make the address bar disappear, but what happens, is that it scrolls to the right position, but the address bar doesn't go away.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

I am testing on Android 4.1/4.4 and Chrome 39.

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836204/chrome-fullscreen-api, you can manage this effect, but only after a user interacts with the page.