# stay full screen in html 5

Tags: javascript, html, video

I would like to run an online experiment where I would display very short videos (500ms, ~50Kb) full screen. Then collect an answer by asking observers to click on 1 of 2 buttons, then play the next video (50-100 videos in total). So I know I can display videos full screen in HTML5 by asking participants to request it (I can't do that automatically as far as I understand). However it is important for me that the experiment remains full screen during its entire duration (5-10 minutes), including during the response parts where it is not a video but a simple html page with 2 buttons on it. I don't want participants to have to request a full screen on every video. Is it possible in principle? I guess I need to change the page between the video and the response screen, is the refresh going to make the window blink? Ideally, that wouldn't be noticeable by the participants. Finally, is there a way to make sure the participants remained full screen (is there meta-data that tells me if they quit full screen mode)?

Thanks a lot.

Baptiste

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force it, it is prohibited by the Chrome Fullscreen API, meaning that, for security reason, in the majority of modern browsers, it must be executed in the context of a user-interactive event firing, not on the terms of the document.

Feel free to browse the [Chrome Fullscreen API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836204/chrome-fullscreen-api) page, or another answer on Stack Overflow titled, [How to Open a Web Page Automatically in Full Screen Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355370/how-to-open-a-web-page-automatically-in-full-screen-mode).

Comment: Ok thanks. That's what I understood. However, once the user requested the fullscreen mode, can I let it open when switching page or alternatively can I close the video and open a new one without leaving fullscreen?