# How to get the full screen mode of a web page

Tags: reactjs, fullscreen

I am developing react web page. and what I'm wanting to do is,
when a button pressed I want my web page to view on full-screen mode. How can I implement that 
Is there a way to do this without using any external packages

Comment: Hope you mean to say F11 functionality of chrome (shotcut of windows) ?
Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/25246044/7979337

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenfull Package

Comment: I have done something similar in an App. You should be able to use native JS to achieve this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836204/chrome-fullscreen-api