# "Going FullScreen" and "Exiting FullScreen" signals?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension that would send a http request to a local server to increase screen brightness when a website goes fullscreen (In this case Youtube and Netflix) and send another request when the screen gets out of Fullscreen mode.

I have searched around on the web and found that I can probably constantly keep check if the browser is in FullScreen mode or not (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23971798/4617277) but haven't found out if there is some sort of signal/event that I could subscribe to ?

I intend to use this extension mainly on Linux based systems.

Comment: Searching for "fullscreen change event" I see [fullscreenchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/fullscreenchange) event.

Comment: @wOxxOm Presumably this would work if every page was injected into with a listening code. I'm guessing the unspoken requirement here is "any tab goes into this mode" and the question is rather "is there a Chrome extension API for it"