# How do we change the properties of an address bar using either C# or Java Script/Jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I will be encrypting my own web pages (as opposed to relying solely on Godaddy or whoever my client chooses to use). And I'd like to know how to change the properties of a user's address bar. Godaddy puts a pretty green bar across the address bar. I'm using C# and Java Script/Jquery. But I don't seem to see anything beyond the favicon.ico which is used for the title as opposed to the address bar below it.

Comment: I've gone to godaddy.com in both FF and Chrome and don't see any green in the address bar.

Comment: Well you're not able to change something like that from Javascript. The Green Bar isn't put there by GoDaddy. It's simply because it's a trusted Root Authority (or Certificate Authority, I forget which) and that's where the certificate is from. So the browser changes that part because it trusts the encryption certificate. When you self-sign code, it's not trusted, so it won't be trusted by the browser. The only way to do what you want is to get a trusted certificate

Comment: @Barmar Visit it using https

Comment: @Ian, I can appreciate that. But I have the ability to encrypt my site. So should I not be able to let the browsers know it's encrypted? The fact is that someone was responsible for the design of the address bar when the site was encrypted. And if it's Google Chrome or I.E. then shouldn't they design the address bar the same for every hosting provider? But I don't believe they do, do they?

Comment: @JamesKhouri-iDevJunkie The point is that you can't be trusted :) There are specific companies like GoDaddy that have proven to provide secure encryption, so they are trusted. The whole address bar "design" is created by the browser. There are certain levels of certificates, and the highest one, like GoDaddy's https, is displayed differently than a "normal" one. And yes, the design is the same no matter the certificate authority, but the information/details obviously change

Comment: @JamesKhouri-iDevJunkie Sorry there isn't more of a solution/explanation for you :( If this helps, look at http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx?ci=72977 . The "Green Bar" isn't exactly implemented the same across browsers, but there's a point that it's a higher level than other certificates. How the bar is displayed is up to the browser, based on the certificate. Like you said, the things you can control are the `favicon` and the `title`.

Comment: @Ian Why can't I see a way to choose your answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green bar is your browsers indicator of a more secure https (SSL) certificate than yours. Such encryption costs more.

A different browser might show a different layout and/or color and there is no way you can predict or set how it will look on your visitor's computer. If your website is intended to only run on computers you control (such as a kiosk or trade show or intranet use), you can reach your goal:

- [full-screen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900701/onclick-go-full-screen)
- browser extensions
- Web View embedded in your application
- ...

Comment: I guess what I was hoping to achieve was encrypting the site myself (as I found information on MSDN to do so). But I guess I understand that having the ability to make something 'seem' encrypted would be dangerous. Thanks for the your answer.

Answer (score 1):

the only way you can change appearances is to write an extension for chrome or mozilla. you actually have to change the skin, you cant just manipulate the browser with js, do you realize the implications of security!?

http://www.chromeextensions.org/

Comment: Do I understand the implications of security? Yes I do. It's just that I trust myself implicitly and feel the world should too. :P Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What I was hoping to do was whatever Godaddy did to encrypt the site (found information on MSDN for that) and just write code to help users to see it's safe. I guess I just didn't realize that the confirmation look of the browser's address bar was the result of the browser itself. Makes sense. Thanks again

Comment: yes I wish people would trust me too so I can do cool things lol @iDevJunkie