# How do I bind "Exit Full Screen f11" browser button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I Created a link to go full screen with this code, from [onclick go full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900701/onclick-go-full-screen)

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
    if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||    
       (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {  
      document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();  
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {  
      document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();  
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {  
      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);  
    }  
  } else {  
    if (document.cancelFullScreen) {  
      document.cancelFullScreen();  
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {  
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();  
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {  
      document.webkitCancelFullScreen();  
    }  
  }  
}
```

Now, when browser is in full screen mode, how do I bind browser's **"Exit full screen f11"** button that pops at top of window **to do something as a callback** after window comes to normal mode by **exiting full screen** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching, I found that it is not possible to bind that button. Since that is browser's native button, which is out of scope of DOM.

> So, Use keypress event listener's instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
var fullScreen = 0;
$( window ).keydown(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 122) {
        if(fullScreen == 1) {
            ....
            //your code goes here
            ....
        }
        fullScreen = (fullScreen == 1) ? 0 : 1;
    }
});
```

I think this should work in most browser

Comment: please accept this answer if it solves your question... meanwhile i'll try to test it on different browsers...

Comment: Actually, I used this and other alternatives such as clicking ESC button. But i wanted to bind click that exit full screen button.