# Trigger Browser Full Screen Mode via Javascript

Tags: javascript

When a YouTube video goes full screen, it is relative to the monitor rather than the browser.

How can I trigger a browsers full screen mode to display a webpage relative to the monitor with JS?

Comment: Modern browsers have a full screen button, when it is pressed, the screen becomes the borders of your browser. But you cannot replicate this with CSS because the page is always contained in your browser

Comment: Can you toggle this with JS? I want it triggered by a site action, rather than browser action.

Comment: If that's possible, I suppose

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900701/onclick-go-full-screen.

Comment: When it appears to be a duplicate, I guess I'm supposed to just delete this question?

Comment: @Ryanthehouse deletion or not, it is up to you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a fullscreen browser API in most modern browsers. You can invoke them in Javascript with commands like

```
if(document.fullscreenEnabled){
    document.getElementById("myimage").requestFullscreen();
}
```

More info at https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-full-screen-api/

Keep in mind you'll have to add much more fullscreen handling code in addition to this.