# scrolling disabled in the webpage when full screen mode is triggered

Tags: javascript, css, fullscreen

I am trying to get fullscreen mode using javscript. So I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10627148/1848140) answer and working on it. But I found out that, when I am triggering full screen using this **code** scrollbar disappears and scroll is disabled. But if I am using F11 to trigger the same, scrollbar appears and scroll is possible.
 I had tried to give `overflow:auto` to body but it does'nt have anyy effect. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nagaraju2905/6hcmzu40/) is the fiddle that reproduces the same issue. When you run the fiddle you will be able to see that all paragraphs are not visible.

Note: I am using Firefox 45.

**HTML :**

```
<body>
      <input type="button" value="click to go fullscreen" onclick="requestFullScreen()">
      <p>
       1 some text to make screnn bigger
      </p>
        <p>
         2some text to make screnn bigger
      </p>
        <p>
       3 some text to make screnn bigger
      </p>
        <p>
        4some text to make screnn bigger
      </p>
        <p>
        5some text to make screnn bigger
      </p>
        <p>
       6 some text to make screnn bigger
      </p>
        <p>
        7some text to make screnn bigger
      </p>  <p>
       8 some text to make screnn bigger
      </p>
        <p>
       9 some text to make screnn bigger
      </p>
        <p>
       10 some text to make screnn bigger
      </p>
        <p>
       11some text to make screnn bigger
      </p>
        <p>
        12 some text to make screnn bigger
      </p>
        <p>
        13 some text to make screnn bigger
      </p>
        <p>
       14 some text to make screnn bigger
      </p>
        <p>
       15 some text to make screnn bigger
      </p>
        <p>
        16 some text to make screnn bigger
      </p>
    </body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function requestFullScreen() {

  var el = document.body;

  // Supports most browsers and their versions.
  var requestMethod = el.requestFullScreen || el.webkitRequestFullScreen || el.mozRequestFullScreen || el.msRequestFullScreen;

  if (requestMethod) {

    // Native full screen.
    requestMethod.call(el);

  } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") {

    // Older IE.
    var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

    if (wscript !== null) {
      wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Fiddle working fine on Chrome 59. Not working on Firefox 54. Yeah, definitely Firefox issue.

Comment: @yuriy636 any work around to fix it?

Comment: Still testing, for now I found a page which works fine in Firefox http://robnyman.github.io/fullscreen/index-high-content.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `el` to `document.documentElement` and the scrolling will work in Firefox.

```
var el = document.documentElement;
```

*It will break in JSFiddle while using Chrome(because of iframe policies I guess), but I don't think that's the main use.*

Comment: I verified it in chrome and firefox no issues.