# Flash to take the view to fullscreen

Tags: javascript, flash, browser, actionscript

I need a link to invoke a flash movie (with javascript) that takes the view to full screen, and show the page content. Exactly as if the user has pressed F11. Is there such flash movie?

**Edit**
This is different from what the flash player does on Youtube and other video sites in that the flash *movie* has no content to show and after the page goes fullscreen I want the normal page content to be displayed. The only role of the flash object would be invoking the fullscreen mode.

Comment: no sorry, no flash goes to fullscreen, youtube and every other video site is a myth....

Comment: @Neal Very funny. Anyway to clarify, the difference is, I need the flash to cause the fullscreen, and yet the normal content of the page to be displayed (not even a see through, as links and other page elements should be functional as normal).

Comment: Full screen has to be triggered by a UI user event such as mouse click. Anything other then user interaction is a security violation and will break. The best you can do is emulate full screen with a new window( browser permissions aside ). Even dispatching the events through code wont trigger it, trust me i have tried

Comment: One way *might be* to write action script to read the page content and somehow import that into the flash. Then the flash *movie* would be showing the same content in full screen. Anyway, I don't know enough action script to even say if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript (and therefore Flash) does not have access to activating full-screen mode (and thank god it doesn't!).

The best you can do is measure the user's screen size and open a new window that emulates this layout.

See: [How to make the window full screen with Javascript (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)

Answer (score 1):

No. Flash full screen mode (which can only be triggered with a click) is independent from browser full screen mode (which not all browsers have anyway).

Comment: I have no problem with it being only triggered with a click, and it makes no difference wether it is a *real* browser fullscreen or a flash fullscreen. All I need is the flash would expose the page content underneath after it goes fullscreen. Is that possible?

Comment: No. It still isn't. It's completely independent.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Better to know it's not possible than not.