# Maximise browser window and height

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in [pure] JavaScript to maximise a browser window and increase its height such that it doesn't have scroll bars? Even if the height becomes greater than the screen.

Thanks all

### Update

The reason I want to do this is so that I can capture the full page of the site as an image using selenium. The native selenium functions do not work on all browsers and do not do exactly what I want so I've built my own image capture in C sharp but I need some JS code to increase height of browser.

Comment: `html, body{ overflow-y:none; }` if you don't want scrollbars.

Comment: @Shaz - its not that I want scrollbars, its for testing on selenium so that I can takescreen shots of the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pretty solution, but this is as close as you get: [How to make the window full screen with Javascript (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)

Answer (score 0):

The `html` element has the `overflow` property added to it with a value of `hidden`.

Check [this](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/hide_scrollbar.cfm) to hide the browser scrollbar