# Full Screen Page by pressing button instead of F11

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to make in Javascript full screen windows (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)
>   [Simulate JavaScript Key Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

I want to simulate F11 by the user pressing a button using javascript only, is this possible? I know its possible with a flash page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28589187/3212513  - your answer is here

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there is any officially supported way because browsers are such a popular attack-vector, faking user keypresses would be an effective way to do bad things (vis click-fraud). That said, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events) has some suggestions for simulating keypresses.