# Why trigger F11 press event doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, keyevent

I just read this question: [Full Screen Page by pressing button instead of F11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427690/full-screen-page-by-pressing-button-instead-of-f11)
The op asked to replace <kbd>F11</kbd> with other hot keys, so I'm wondering that maybe I can simulate press <kbd>F11</kbd> to get things work.
I learned that I can use trigger in JQuery to simulate key press event, so I do something like this:

```
$("body").keyup(function (e) {
    alert(e.which);
});
var e = $.Event("keyup");
e.which = 122; // # Key code of F11
$("body").trigger(e);
```

When I run this, I got the alert says 122, but it seems that it doesn't give the hoped result.  Is there a restriction there?

I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ap295/5/

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to execute key commands by just triggering events programmatically. That would be insane.

Comment: let's trigger `CMD` + `Q` or `ALT` + `F4` ? All serious browsers will not execute that due to Javascript.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is the one :) to detect it ...

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
   if(e.which==122){
       e.preventDefault();//kill anything that browser may have assigned to it by default
       //do what ever you wish here :) 
       alert('F11 pressed');
       return false;
   }
});
```

but triggering it (**NOT POSSIBLE**)

But you will not prevent the browser from full screen :) ...
Reson given is that , lets say I have full screened it somehow, and wish to toggle out of it using <kbd>F11</kbd> but u are preventing me, I would have to restart PC, [computer illiterates] which poses security risk as you are preventing a user from doing something he is expecting to do, and they may think PC is broken or something :) so ...there you are.

Comment: I do want to let the browser do what they assigned to it by default..that is turn to fullscreen mode

Comment: Like I said you are asking to take control of some persons keyboard which is stupid, lets say i visit FB, fb then triggers, f11,and then f, and then u, n then triggers the comment button, basically all I had to do is login on fb, then fb would type in what ever they wanted on my profile ... do you understand ?

Answer (score 10):

You can not do this. The linked answer in that question provides a way with jQuery to simulate key-presses, within the jQuery event framework.

You simply can not trigger or fake keypresses. So the answer of this question is:

**No, this is impossible**

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to override the browser's built-in hotkeys from within a web page.

You *might* be able to do it in a browser extension, but that's would surely be serious overkill just to change the application's hotkeys.

In any case, why would you even want to override the standard keyboard shortcuts? I don't get that. They've been standard for a long time; most users will be familiar with them, and will find it very odd if they've been changed to something else.

Comment: **why would you even want to override the standard keyboard shortcuts**: I think it's nicer to let the user click a button wrote "fullscreen" than alert to tell them: "Please press F11 key now"

Answer (score 2):

Don't look at is as a question of "How do I trigger F11?" - look at is as "How do I trigger or simulate full-screen?"

With older versions of IE you can open a new window straight into full-screen:

```
window.open(someURLorOther, '', 'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=auto');
```

Or you can use `window.open` to open a new window of a specific size.

Or you can try to resize the current window to fill the screen:

```
moveTo(0,0);
resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
```

However **just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*.** You should *never* resize the current window - this annoys practically everyone. Opening a new window to a size you choose is more reasonable, though if it's too big it can be annoying, and on a normal web page (where by "normal" I probably mean not some kind of browser-based data-entry app) it is nicer not to open new windows.