# Programmatically hit functional keys using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulate Keypress With jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468384/simulate-keypress-with-jquery)
>   [Why trigger F11 press event doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428242/why-trigger-f11-press-event-doesnt-work)

How to programmatically hit functional keys using jQuery?
Is there any way to simulate the functional keys with jQuery?

Thanks,
Naveen.

Comment: [vanilla solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

Comment: You can't press functional keys via javascript. I often see this question asked in regards to pushing f11 to force full screen mode. Is this what you are after?

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.trigger({ type: 'keypress', which: character });
```

And [here is a list of the key codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) you can pass

Comment: This question should be closed. there are like 15 dupes of it out there already. We need to start pushing users to search the site before just asking a redundant question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it gives the code of the corresponding key, but it doesn't functional, like if i want to simulate f12 key it shows me the corresponding code 123 but it did nothing. how to get the key functional.

Comment: Please review the answers provided in the comments to your question.

Comment: please have a look into the link http://jsfiddle.net/Rn3Ld/