# Full screen a web page in HTML5 in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, fullscreen

My task requires me to create a page in HTML5 with the following requirements:

1. Compatible with Internet Explorer 10
2. Has an option to enable Full screen view of certain excel reports on page as per filter values
3. Does not reload the already loaded report, must hide other contents of the page and should hide the taskbar and toolbar
4. Should have an option to exit full screen view without a reload

I just want the report that has loaded on the page to be displayed in full screen.

I have tried `window.open ("www.stackoverflow.com","","fullscreen=yes");`
But this opens a new window and reloads the contents

I have tried requestFullScreen() but according to this [page](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/full-screen/index.html) this feature is not supported in IE

And also hoped [triggering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428242/why-trigger-f11-press-event-doesnt-work) F11 key would be an answer, but that doesn't work as well..

Is there anyone who could help me find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

you can precise the destination : `this.href`

`window.open(this.href, 'test', 'fullscreen=yes, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no, resizable=yes, scrollbars=no, status=no');`

EDIT : I've found a solution [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-full-screen-api/)

Try to use the HTML5 Full-Screen API

Comment: Window.Open opens a new window all together, but as per my requirement, it should open in same window, without reloading the page. Something that makes the taskbar and toolbar disappear.

Comment: As mentioned in the link you have provided, requestFullScreen works only for Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Not IE.

(I remember cursing IE when I first read that page)

Comment: yes you're right but "There’s no support in Internet Explorer or Opera yet, but I would suggest you use the ‘ms’ and ‘o’ prefixes for future proofing." so for the moment i think that haven't other solution that windows.open.

Comment: Opera will support it very soon once the first webkit based version is released. Upcoming IE support is not yet announced