# How can I call two functions by pressing F11?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a webpage for science fair to test student's abilities to detect a phishing website. The website will change to look like the Windows log in screen. I need the functions that do this to activate when <kbd>F11</kbd> is pressed. how might I do this?

Comment: try this => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428242/why-trigger-f11-press-event-doesnt-work. using that function will allow u to trigger whatever functions you want.

Comment: By binding to the `keypress` event (on the `document`) and checking for the `F11` key (keyCode 122).  You might also need to prevent the default action (usually fullscreen) with `preventDefault()`.

Comment: What part(s) of this do you need help with?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not using the F11 key, as this is a common shortcut for launching the "full screen" mode in some current browsers. Hence, the browser developers may want to protect the browser from a page author overriding this shortcut.

Comment: that is actually why i need it to be f11

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode===122){
        function1();
        function2();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probaby [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), also you should use [`e.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/).  Also, the question doesn't even mention jQuery in the first place.