# Fullscreen current page with button press

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

I would like to use the code below but want it to happen to the current page when I click the link. Is this possible? Thanks in advance. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Open window to fullscreen without f11</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin(url){
var sw=screen.width;
var sh=screen.height;
newwin=window.open(url,'newwin','width='+sw+',height='+sh+',top=0,left=0,scrolling=0,toolbar=0,direc tories=0,menubar=0,location=0');
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.codingforums.com" onclick="openWin(this.href);return false;">Coding Forums</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you actually include the results of your tests in your questions? What happens if you try this code? What's the error message or what else is wrong?

Comment: It is clear that the asker wants to load a new url fullscreen into current window. The code shown will attempt to fullscreen a NEW window (but won't) and Hawkes wants to try to do that with the main browser window

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full Screen Page by pressing button instead of F11.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427690/full-screen-page-by-pressing-button-instead-of-f11) which is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using window.location.href instead of window.open? window.open is used to open new browser window.

Comment: He wants to change the window url AND remove some chrome

Comment: basically I just want to keep the same page running but make the window fullscreen like a popup with a click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

No it is NOT possible to open a url and *CHANGE THE CHROME* in the same window and you should not try either.

There is a horrific hack which opens a new window and closes the parent, but that is even worse.

There USED to be a fullscreen parameter but it was luckily removed. It is not up to the web "designer" to decide the size of the user's window nor to try and remove their history by closing the main window.

If you search for fullscreen here, you will get many, among this one:

[How to make the window full screen with Javascript (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)