# Full Screen Browser window (Like F11)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am creating a web application. 
How do I change the browser from normal mode to fullscreen mode (like <kbd>F11</kbd>),  but I don't want to open a popup for this. 
I want to convert the same window to fullscreen mode.

The requirement  is: there is a button on the page, and it's a toggle button for changing normal mode to fullscreen mode and fullscreen mode to normal mode

Comment: and...? where's the question?

Comment: An answer to a very similar question can be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen

Answer (score 1):

Try this javascript code below.

```
<script>
function fullScreenMode(url) {
window.open(url, '', 'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=auto');
}

</script>
```

Comment: The question states "i don't want to open any popup for this". This opens a popup.

Comment: i dot'n want to open a any popup for this, perform operation on same window

Comment: I hope this helps..   function openWindow() {
        window.open("", "_self", "")
        window.close();
        window.open("url", "page", "toolbars=no,location=no,resizable=no")
    }