# Full screen browser window with javascript (cross-browser) or alternatives?

Tags: javascript

Running a web-based app that when full-screen maximizes real-estate for best usage for this type of industry. I need to find a way to link up a javascript function to a button (like pressing F11) that will fully maximize the browser window.

We also have an installer that places .url shortcuts in Windows. A nice alternative would be some sort of parameter that opens the default browser full-screen.

Does anyone have a clean approach? The code provided here is very dirty but *almost* gets the job done: [Full Screen Browser window (Like F11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550989/full-screen-browser-window-like-f11)

Thanks!

Comment: I know that it is possible, I searched for this a long time but I can't find it out. (Google docs PowerPoint does that but I don't know how)

Comment: Goggle docs is likely a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible to full-screen any browsers from a normal html page. IE can do [HTA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (html applications) or run in kiosk mode

`iexplorer.exe -k index.html`

Firefox needs plugins: https://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+kiosk+mode