# How to trigger f11 event of keyboard using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to trigger f11 event of keyboard using javascript or jquery, can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Comment: i want to trigger the same event which takes place when you press the f11 key on your keyboard.Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try using this one:
http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/fullscreen/

Comment: You should be aware though of the [differences](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=794468) between the Fullscreen API and the F11 fullscreen mode.

Comment: Why don't you explain then Tgr?

Answer (score 5):

You can't make people's computers type things through javascript. It violates the sandboxing environment of browsers. I assume that you are trying to make a window go full screen though. This SO question covers that.

[How to make the window full screen with Javascript (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)

Answer (score 4):

I'm use this code:

```js
function go_full_screen(){
  var elem = document.documentElement;
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="go_full_screen();">Full Screen / Compress Screen</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

To trigger  event Keypress of <kbd>F11</kbd> key like from keyboard, we need this..

Call this function on any event..

```
function mKeyF11(){
    var e = new Event('keypress');
    e.which = 122; // Character F11 equivalent.
    e.altKey=false;
    e.ctrlKey=false;
    e.shiftKey=false;
    e.metaKey=false;
    e.bubbles=true;
    document.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

This is pure Javascript function and don't need jQuery to support it..

Update: Chrome prevents JavaScript key-press. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44496707/chrome-eats-javascript-keydown-event-handler-on-f11-key-press-when-browser-is-a?rq=1)

For chrome we can use the following.

```
if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>

function toggleFullscreen() {
    var isFullscreen = document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || false;

    if (isFullscreen) {
        exitFullscreen();
    } else {
        enterFullscreen();
    }
}

function enterFullscreen() {
    var element = document.documentElement;
    if (element.requestFullscreen) {
        element.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
}

function exitFullscreen() {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    }
}

document.getElementById("toggleButton").addEventListener("click", toggleFullscreen);
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Working code sample:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpTextField, false);
function keyUpTextField (e) 
{
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if(keyCode==122){/*ejecutaAlgo*/}
}
```

Comment: OP do not want to execute something when f11 is pressed. He wants to simulate a key press.