# JavaScript 'keyUp' event not triggered after exiting fullscreen

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, keyup

I've got a very strange behavior of the **keyUp** event. JS snippet is attached. Tested on Chrome/Chromium.

Steps to reproduce:

1. **F11** to go fullscreen
2. Press down **A** key (leave it pressed)
3. Press **F11** to exit fullscreen
4. Release the **A** key

Result - NO output lines in the console! Why is that? I expected to see something, but it seems that exiting a fullscreen disables the future keyUp events. In my case I start a job by pressing a key, and need to stop it after the release. Currently it continues to run.

The question is - how do I get it working?

Could that be a Chrome/Chromium bug? I've tried Firefox now - **keyup** event is successfully triggered.

```js
i = 0;

window.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    console.log("key up, " + i);
    i = i+1;
});
```

Comment: Seems like focus is lost .After exiting full screen I needed to click on the screen to get it work

Comment: @ManosKounelakis, no difference to me. Are you clicking after exiting fullscreen and then releasing the key prints the output for you?

Comment: @Alexey You may just want to remove step 1 from your instructions altogether, being that stack snippets provide an on-screen console.

Comment: @TylerRoper, true, thanks! Built-in console is good enough

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in chrome but it does in firefox. I guess it depends on how the browser is handling the keypress event when f11 is pressed. Maybe chrome is using preventDefault on the event. This answer here explains why it does that:

[Chrome eats javascript keydown event handler on F11 key press, when browser is already in full screen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44496707/chrome-eats-javascript-keydown-event-handler-on-f11-key-press-when-browser-is-a)

Comment: What can I do then? In my case I start a job by pressing a key, and need to stop it after the release. Currently it continues to run

Comment: You can use fullscreenchange event which is fired in chrome when full screen changes as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126106/capture-esc-event-when-exiting-full-screen-mode

Comment: I need to call a JS function after the releasing a key, not right after exiting a fullscreen

Comment: As explained, due to security reason, chrome wants to give full control to the user if the user wants to exit out of full screen. So it cancels all the events and gives the control to the user. Since keyup is a cancelable event, it is cancelled. So you lose the event whenever you press f11. Sadly you can do nothing about it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanations. I see that **fullscreenchange** also doesn't work with **F11**. So things are bad with this?!

Comment: It will work but you won't be able to achieve what you want

Comment: Please show how. I have a workaround idea, if I can get "fullscreen exit" event in JS