# How do you make a Raphael canvas go full screen?

Tags: javascript, html, raphael, fullscreen

Is there a way to make a Raphael canvas/Paper expand to full screen?  When I say full screen I mean the entire screen, not just the browser area, similar to clicking full screen on a Flash video.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do full screen the way that you want too.  Check out this link though: [How to make the window full screen with Javascript (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen).  I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I look forward to this becoming more cross-browser compatible.