# fullscreen through javascript

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

well making a page fullscreen is one of my favorite topics but whenever I have thought of doing it, I have always received one answer and that is, it is only done with flash.
For the first time today I saw one that is not done with flash, can someone tell me how exactly it is done, so I could atlast full my dream of using it ^^
here is the image 
http://content.screencast.com/users/cryoffalcon/folders/Jing/media/5ac91f6f-ed2f-4312-b8e3-3ac9771f5497/2012-04-13_0001.png

and here is the link to the page where this fullscreen button exists.
http://tutorialzine.com/2010/09/html5-canvas-slideshow-jquery/

Comment: Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode The function is called `requestFullScreen()`

Comment: There's a cool demo here: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/fullscreen.html

Comment: Well thanks guys, I have seen one thing, that here on stackoverflow if a person don't realize that you are dump they give you AWESOME answers really quickly. As people over here are damn smart. I am extremely dump in scripts but this much information was enough to make me understand and use it. Thanks a lot, but I have one question it is only for firefox and chrome what about our STEP CHILD (IE)?

Comment: @CryOfFaclon: The fullscreen API is still just a "proposal", a "draft".  It's not supported in IE.

Comment: There are plenty of duplicates of this question (like this one, for instance): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen

Answer (score 7):

Some browser support this through html5.

Try

```
var docElm = document.documentElement;
if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
    docElm.requestFullscreen();
}
else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
}
else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
}
```