# fullscreen on click - Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs4, fullscreen

How can I make my browser switch to fullscreen mode by clicking on a button, I'm looking for any type of solution, I mean based on Ext JS, Javascript, HTML5 or other tricks if you have one

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make in Javascript full screen windows (stretching all over the screen)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this solution

```
var docElm = document.documentElement;
if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
   docElm.requestFullscreen();
}
else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
   docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
}
else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
   docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
}
```

and for cancelling fullscreen :

```
if (document.exitFullscreen) {
   document.exitFullscreen();
}
else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
   document.mozCancelFullScreen();
}
else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
    document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
}
```

this work for me using ExtJS 4.0.7 with chrome

full explanation [here](http://css.dzone.com/articles/pragmatic-introduction-html5).

Answer (score 2):

Not widely supported but there’s https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode