# How to create a Full Screen button without flash?

Tags: flash, html, fullscreen

I am trying to make a website without flash; however, I am stuck on trying to make an icon which when clicked will make the page full screen (equivalent of f11). If I had to do it in flash, its simple, but how can I do it without flash? Are there any html5 options available?

I saw a few solutions but they are not similar to the flash solutions I have found...
Everything I have found seems to be like this example:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/dhtml/article.php/3470521/So-You-Want-A-FullScreen-Browser-Huh.htm

Can someone help on this?

Comment: You probably have a good reason for wanting a fullscreen web page, but make sure you think very carefully before doing so! Taking away the user's address bar, tabs and chrome has some major usability ramifications.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen

Comment: Hi jonathan.. thanks for warning me about usability.. i believe application is demanding that.. for example.. its looks easy for me to make awesome presentations in web based way.. videos.. photos.. animations.. transition.. use of web services.. and automatic content updation.. so this question is solely for presentation purpose... thanks anyway!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Only the latest chrome and firefox support html5 fullscreen at the moment.

See here: http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/26517/using-the-browsers-new-html5-fullscreen-capabilities

and here: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/

Comment: Thanks.. your answer is really awesome.. and this is what i exactly wanted.. thank you!!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this solution using JavaScript and it is of course browser dependent.This is i think as close as you can be to what flash offers
[How to make the window full screen with Javascript (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)