# Switch window between normal and full-screen mode

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is it possible to force window to **switch** between **normal** and **full-screen** mode by JavaScript (*no jQuery*)..?

I know how to open a new window in full-screen, but that is not what I need.

Comment: Have you read this? http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-full-screen-api/#fbid=hhFRAbSolMC

Comment: @Neil - Nice, but I need Opera support (if possible).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make in Javascript full screen windows (stretching all over the screen)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's now a proper [fullscreen API](http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/)  (first [proposed by Mozilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:FullScreenAPI) and later released as a [W3C proposal](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html))  has been implemented by Webkit (Safari 5.1+/Chrome 15+) and Firefox (10+).  [A brief history and usage examples here.](http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/)  Note that IE10 will allegedly **not** support the API.

Comment: Any chance to send "F11" key to browser by script?

Comment: Nope.  Script having the ability to control your keyboard would be a major security problem.  You might be able to do something in an [extension](http://dev.opera.com/addons/extensions/), but that obviously requires an install.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the experimental [FullScreen API](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#api).

- [Using full-screen mode on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode)
- [W3c Fullscreen Living Spec](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html)
- [Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/fullscreen)

If you are not satisfied with the browser support, there is one more option: display a message to the user about how F11 switches to Fullscreen mode. Used this as a fallback option in a recent webapp I worked on, and the feedback was satisfactory.