# How to open a web page automatically in full screen mode

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

How do I open a web page automatically in full screen mode?

I am looking for a solution to open an web page automatically in full screen mode, without expecting user to users press F11 or any other browser-specifc key.

I've searched a lot, but I just could not find a solution.

Is there a script or library or browser specific API available to help me achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make HTML5 video fullscreen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055214/is-there-a-way-to-make-html5-video-fullscreen). Even though the question itself my not be a duplicate to this one, the accepted answer would match here too. In any case have a look at the [HTML5 fullscreen API](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-full-screen-api/)

Comment: Found a similar question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495373/how-to-make-browser-full-screen-using-f11-key-event-through-javascript]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch window between normal and full-screen mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436376/switch-window-between-normal-and-full-screen-mode)

Comment: It's not possible to open the page in full screen without user interaction (clicking on a button etc.) because it would be extremely annoying.

Comment: https://github.com/kayahr/jquery-fullscreen-plugin Works in Webkit-based browsers (Like Chrome and Safari), Firefox and IE11+ and etc

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For Chrome via [Chrome Fullscreen API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836204/chrome-fullscreen-api)

Note that for (Chrome) security reasons it cannot be called or executed automatically, there must be an interaction from the user first. *(Such as button click, keydown/keypress etc.)*

```
addEventListener("click", function() {
    var
          el = document.documentElement
        , rfs =
               el.requestFullScreen
            || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
            || el.mozRequestFullScreen
    ;
    rfs.call(el);
});
```

Javascript Fullscreen API as [demo](http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen)'d by [David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen) that seems to be a cross browser solution

```
// Find the right method, call on correct element
function launchFullScreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullScreen) {
    element.requestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
  }
}

// Launch fullscreen for browsers that support it!
launchFullScreen(document.documentElement); // the whole page
launchFullScreen(document.getElementById("videoElement")); // any individual element
```

Answer (score 2):

Only works in IE:

```
window.open ("mapage.html","","fullscreen=yes");  
window.open('','_parent','');  
window.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

It's better to try to simulate a webbrowser by yourself.You don't have to stick with Chrome or IE or else thing.

If you're using Python,you can try package pyQt4 which helps you to simulate a webbrowser.
By doing this,there will not be any security reasons and you can set the webbrowser to show in full screen mode automatically.

Answer (score -1):

You can go fullscreen automatically by putting this code in:

```
var elem = document.documentElement; if (elem.requestFullscreen) { elem.requestFullscreen() }
```

demo: https://codepen.io/ConfidentCoding/pen/ewLyPX

note: does not always work for security reasons. but it works for me at least. does not work when inspecting and pasting the code.

Comment: You should probably provide a little bit more information other than "does not always work". When does it not work? Why?

Answer (score -2):

view full size page large
                                           (function () {
    var viewFullScreen = document.getElementById("view-fullscreen");
    if (viewFullScreen) {
        viewFullScreen.addEventListener("click", function () {
            var docElm = document.documentElement;
            if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
                docElm.requestFullscreen();
            }
            else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
            }
            else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            }
        }, false);
    }
    })();

```html
<div class="container">      
            <section class="main-content">
                                    <center><a href="#"><button id="view-fullscreen">view full size page large</button></a><center>
                                           <script>(function () {
    var viewFullScreen = document.getElementById("view-fullscreen");
    if (viewFullScreen) {
        viewFullScreen.addEventListener("click", function () {
            var docElm = document.documentElement;
            if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
                docElm.requestFullscreen();
            }
            else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
            }
            else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            }
        }, false);
    }
    })();</script>
                                           </section>
</div>
```

for view demo clcik here [demo of click to open page in fullscreen](https://uditmehra631.blogspot.com/2019/10/clcik-to-open-website-in-full-screen.html#)

Answer (score -3):

```
window.onload = function() {
    var el = document.documentElement,
        rfs = el.requestFullScreen
        || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
        || el.mozRequestFullScreen;
    rfs.call(el);
};
```

Comment: I doubt that this can ever help or even work at all. In order to convince me otherwise, please explain how you mean this to work and solve the problem.