# I need to make web-app work as windows full screen app. In IE-11 (last) for PC (WIN-7), full screen mode, with a button to close it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I need to make web-app work as windows full screen app.

In Microsoft Internet Explorer - 11 (last) for PC (Windows-7), full screen mode, with a button to close it.

.

The first task is a fullscreen mode.

I can make fullscreen easily (Thanks to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355370/how-to-open-a-web-page-automatically-in-full-screen-mode))

```
window.open ("mapage.html","","fullscreen=yes");  
window.open('','_parent','');  
window.close();
```

It work perfectly but only for "localhost", once I put files to the server the 'fullscreen' appears to be not fully fullscreen, but it also shows window header with /close/ and /minimize/ buttons and the /address bar/. And it reveals IE.

.

The second task is a button to close it.
Luckily IE window may be closed with simple

```
window.close();
```

But IE asks approval and it reveals itself. I find a way to bypass it with the code from above that I use to make IE work in fullscreen. Unfortunately, I cannot use this fullscreen solution. So If there would be another, please, take to account that I would need the close button for all application.

Comment: can you use an HTA, or does this have to run from the web?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have web server logic including DB usage in this app.

Comment: well, you can use the HTA to iframe your remote url, and still get the menubar/fameborder, and other OS integration options HTA provides. much like a cordova app that just embeds a webview.

Comment: Thanks. If this possible, it would be an option for me, if only I had more experience with HTA.

Comment: Why people minus me? It was what my boss wanted and I did not find similar question anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what I came up with:

Option 1

Use something to run Internet Explorer in kiosk mode.

like a .bat file

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -k "http://google.com/"
```

or Delphi (to have an .exe file):

```
var filename, parameters: string;
begin
  filename := '"iexplore.exe"'; 
  parameters := ' -k "http://google.com/"';
  ShellExecute(handle,'open',PAnsiChar(filename), PAnsiChar(parameters), nil , SW_MAXIMIZE);  
end;
```

Option 2

Use Delphi with EmbeddedWB component.

```
EmbeddedWB1.Navigate('http://google.com/');
```

One string of code and I have my own browser with or without address panel.