# Full screen "f11" modus on a specific wordpress page

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, fullscreen

I got a specific page that I want in full screen mode like if you press F11.

How can I fix this page to get in the full screen mode?

The page contains a full screen slide show.

Thanks for your help.

****** UPDATE ******

I figured out to create a button that goes to the full screen mode.

Still I would like to know if it's possible to load full screen instantly when the page is entered.

Comment: Instruct the user to press F11 for fullscreen if they want fullscreen. I would consider doing it for them bad design (if even possible)

Comment: It's true that going fullscreen without user consent is bad UX. However if you just want to add a friendly fullscreen button to your slideshow (like the one on most video players), that would be reasonable.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355370/how-to-open-a-web-page-automatically-in-full-screen-mode/50279328#50279328

Answer (score -1):

JS has [an experimental fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode) that you can use by calling:

```
elem.requestFullscreen();
```

There are vendor-specific functions that are necessary in some cases.

You could also use a library like [screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/) to abstract the complexity away for you

**Update:** It's not possible to go fullscreen automatically upon load. If you try to use the fullscreen API calls without them being synchronous reactions to user input (click, keypress, etc) they will fail.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.Could you explain me how to implement this on a specific page?