# is there any solution to open browser in full screen mode from command line?

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-applications, cmd

Is there any elegant(or not) solution to open a browser in full screen mode from command line.

Browser full screen api will works only on any user action.

I just need to display a data in a big monitor without showing title bar, menu bar etc. Whether it is possible with browser without any user action.

Whether I could trigger any user action using selenium like tools.

Or anybody could tell any other alternatives to display a data in full screen mode without any user action, but with command line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355370/how-to-open-a-web-page-automatically-in-full-screen-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will switch the browser to fullscreen:

```
getDriver().switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.F11);
```

Comment: Yeah.. it works with selenium, python and firefox webdriver. code is little different when using python but the philosophy is same.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on browser. If it's Chrome, just add a needed parameter to executable:

```
google-chrome --kiosk http://example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The WebDriver.Window interface has the maximize() method for setting the size of a browser window to full screen.

Example usage:

```
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Window.html