# Open HTML page in different monitor full screen Chrome

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, google-chrome-app

This is what I have gone through and successfully implemented:
[Using Chrome app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355370/how-to-open-a-web-page-automatically-in-full-screen-mode)

But the HTML page to be shown in new monitor is generated dynamically, how can I render the HTML page run time and render as chrome app.

I am completely new to chrome app. Any help is appreciated. 
Let me know If you want any more details.

Thank you.

Comment: So, you want a Chrome app that will open an HTML page in fullscreen in a different monitor (expecting this will be a dual-monitor setup)? Have you read the [Apps section](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) of the Chrome documentation along with its APIs?