# Auto trigger F11 when my page is load in jquery

Tags: jquery

I just need to auto clicked F11 when my page is load in Jquery.

Below code is working when i press F11, but i need to auto press F11.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
        if(e.which==122){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('F11 pressed');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a web page automatically in full screen mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355370/how-to-open-a-web-page-automatically-in-full-screen-mode)

Comment: @claudios- This question is related to Jquery, please you should read carefully first.

Comment: You should remove the javascript tag please

Comment: already removed

Answer (score 0):

Run a function and add a Event of trigger in this it will help You. Check my Code Also see Live Demo:- https://jsfiddle.net/Arsh_kalsi01/12L32q3x/2/

```js
PressButton();
function PressButton()
{
    var e = $.Event( "keypress", { which: 122 } );
    $(document).trigger(e);
    if(e.which==122){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('F11 pressed');
      return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Full screen on page load is not allowed on latest browsers. I think also on the older browsers.