# Redirect to a new link in full screen mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage which has data `toggle="fullscreen"`,
When the page is in full screen mode and a **href link** is clicked is it possible for the new link to open in full screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a web page automatically in full screen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355370/how-to-open-a-web-page-automatically-in-full-screen-mode)

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!
[whathaveyoutried.com](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)