# Open reveal.js presentation automatically in full screen mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reveal.js

I want to share some presentations created using reveal.js & I need to find out a solution to open those reveal.js presentations automatically in full screen mode using Google Chrome, without asking users to users press F11.I tried lots of code snippets ,but still couldn't find a solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through this one year ago and had to give up.

Due to the reasonable **security** reasons it is not possible to automatically (without user confirmation/interaction) open a *new* page in fullscreen mode.

There are many similar questions around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436376/switch-window-between-normal-and-full-screen-mode) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355370/how-to-open-a-web-page-automatically-in-full-screen-mode) …

Comment: Thanks mahish. Yes I also ended up with "Failed to execute 'requestFullScreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture." error.